# Is there any way to speed up gem crafting in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found that crafting gems yourself is actually cheaper than buying it from Auction House (considering that you found the starting gems and *Tomes of Secrets* yourself). But the biggest problem now is that crafting the gems takes such a long time. It's just **EXTREMELY** time consuming. So I was wondering if there is any way to speed up that process?

I know that you can disable the pop-up that warns you when you try to salvage rare items, but is there anything like that for speed crafting gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no there is not. The best you could do is sell the gems and buy the upgraded gems from the Auction House.. If the saved time is worth more than the (tiny) amount of saved gold by crafting, then it's worth it.